# looking for example on how to fetch JSON data and use it in a web page

Tags: json

Is there any example/tutorial about how to fetch JSON data from a web server as an HttpRequest, and then it uses the data in a web page? I googled, but did not find one. This one here is too simple http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery's getJSON method to pull the JSON:

```
$.getJSON('/someurl',function(jsonObject){
  // the json object is passed as input to the callback
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/